# Как получить состояние видеокарты NVIDIA?

Tags: c#, cuda, nvidia, видеокарта, нагрузка

Стоит задача, программно получить напряжение, и желательно нагрузку и частоты как в NVIDIA Inspector с видеокарт NVIDIA. Был реализован вариант с использованием nvidia-smi, запускал скрытую cmd с подобным содержанием: "nvidia-smi -i 0 --format=csv,noheader --query-gpu=utilization.gpu", но так нужно делать на 6 картах ежесекундно по 6 параметрам, в итоге эти запросы сильно мешают основной работе видеокарт. Кроме того в nvidia-smi нет команды получения напряжения. В Cudafy, кстати дает только поверхностную информацию: максимальная частота, имя видеокарты и т.п.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi не пробовали?

Comment: посмотрел, да, хорошая библиотека, но определения напряжения всё равно нету